# LX Panel crashing mysteriously after 6 restarts

Tags: lxde, lubuntu

I'm currently experiencing an issue whilst trying to create a bash script that restarts the LXPanel so that the image I use for the background is updated (I'm trying to make a tool that keeps me focused on my current task and this was the best solution I could come up with) - I'm almost there but it seems that the LXPanel crashes ALWAYS after the 6th restart.

I've tried using `lxpanelctl restart` but it does not respond.

On inspection in `/var/log/apport.log` the error returned is that `/usr/bin/lxpanel` is blacklisted. A log-out then log-in brings it back up and I am able to run the program using `lxpanel` in the command line but it's obviously not using the config file.

Is there a way to take this program out of the blacklist and is there any way to find out why this is crashing only on the 6th attempt (I've tested this several times and it is always on the 6th)?

Please let me know if you need more info; I've only been using Linux for the last few months so there's lots I don't know yet.